# Evaluate $\int 5^{-4x} dx$

Tags: integration

The answer turns out to be $\frac{-1}{625^x \ln 625}+ C$.

I am supposed to first put the integral in the form $\int b^x dx = \frac{1}{\ln b}b^x + C$.

I tried various u substitutions, I think I get the answer and then it turns out to be something else, any help would be appreciated,
thanks!

Comment: $5^{-4x}=(5^{-4})^x$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int 5^{-4 x} \mathrm{d}x \stackrel{u=-4x, \mathrm{d}u=-4 \mathrm{d}x}{=} -\frac14 \int 5^u  \mathrm{d}u=-\frac{5^u}{4 \log 5} +c \stackrel{u=-4x}{=}\;\;-\frac{5^{-4 x}}{4 \log 5}+c$$

Answer (score 3):

Write $$5^{-4x} = \mathbb{e}^{\log 5^{-4x}} =  \mathbb{e}^{-4x \log 5}$$
$(-4\log 5)$ is a constant, so the integrand is of the form $\mathbb{e}^{ax}$ which you should be able to integrate.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest (at least to me) is to use the simple identity : if $A=b^{f(x)}$ then $$\log(A)=f(x)\log(b)$$ which rewrite then $$A=e^{f(x)\log(b)}$$ In your case $f(x)=-4 x$ so $$I=\int 5^{-4x} dx=\int e^{-4x \log(5)} dx=-\frac{1}{4 \log(5)} e^{-4x \log(5)}+c$$ and if you prefer, you reuse the initial form and arrive to $$I=-\frac{5^{-4x}}{4 \log(5)} +c$$